# org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'DELETE' not supported

Tags: java

```
@RequestMapping("/category")
public class CategoryController {

    @DeleteMapping("{ids}")
    public R<String> delete(@PathVariable("ids") Long ids){
        categoryService.remove(ids);
        return R.success("删除成功");
    }
}
```

```
const deleteCategory = (ids) => {
  return $axios({
    url: '/category',
    method: 'delete',
    params: { ids }
  })
}
```

URL: http://localhost:8000/category?ids=1397844263642378242

Comment: Are you calling the url with a browser? It won't work for DELETE request. Browsers support only GET. To test DELETE request use Postman o curl. The later on Unix only.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the wrong URL as per the code you defined. You are using `PathVariable` and you passing as query string parameters. Change your js code as follows.

```
const deleteCategory = (ids) => {
  return $axios({
    url: '/category/' + ids,
    method: 'delete'
  })
}
```

Your URL must be URL: http://localhost:8000/category/1397844263642378242

Comment: @xiaowei Can you accept the answer? So if others come across the question they get an answer.

Comment: yes,I accept this answer.